# Postgres: Update date and retain time from timestamp

Tags: postgresql, timestamp

I have a field1 with `timestamp`, `datatype` and values format is `2016-02-23 12:01:30`.

I'm running the query:

```
UPDATE <table> set field1 = '2015-12-31'::timestamp::date where .....
```

The output changes to:

```
  2015-12-31 00:00:00
```

It converts the time to all zero's.  How to change the date and retain the timestamp?

Comment: you do not need to add ::date in the end. just remove it.   `UPDATE <table> set field1 = '2016-02-23'::timestamp where .....`   and you are not giving any value for timestamp so it is taking `00:00:00` by default

Comment: it still changes the timestamp to 00:00:00. :(

Comment: I want to retain the current value of the timestamp and just change the date.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Try this:

```
UPDATE mytable 
SET field1 = '2015-12-31'::timestamp + 
             EXTRACT(HOUR FROM field1) * INTERVAL '1 HOUR' +
             EXTRACT(MINUTE FROM field1) * INTERVAL '1 MINUTE' +
             EXTRACT(SECOND FROM field1) * INTERVAL '1 SECOND' 
WHERE ...
```

[**Demo here**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/6ff13/1)

Comment: Needs an improvement because precision and timezone offset are lost.

Answer (score 12):

There's another way, using the DateTime type.

So if you want to set a table's Date to today, you can use this:

`UPDATE table SET column = current_date::date + column::time;`

Switch `current_date` with "2019-02-23" and it should work as well.

Answer (score 7):

Simply add the new date and the existing time. Here it is:

```
UPDATE mytable 
SET field1 = '2015-12-31'::date + field1::time with time zone
WHERE ...;
```

or even cleaner cut:

```
UPDATE mytable 
SET field1 = field1 - field1::date + '2015-12-31'::date
WHERE ...;
```

Comment: The second way worked for me like a charm. Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

The subtraction of timestamps yields an interval. The resulting interval is can the be added to the desired date to give the desired date with the prior time.

```
with ats (old_tz) as (select now() )  
select old_tz, '2015-12-31'::timestamptz + (old_tz - date_trunc('day', old_tz)) new_tz 
from ats;
```

OOPS. Didn't realize how old this post was until after posting, but still believe it may valuable to future viewers. So I'll just leave it.